# Issue wish visualization / Jagged faces at cube edges

Tags: modeling

[image]

When I createa a solid, this is the way that it appears on the screen. Actually faces are planes but this is what I see, the edge seems to be jagged from far and as soon as I zoom in it becomes perfectly sharp. It never happened to me before. I use 2.9 in solid mode. Maybe I have done something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Hey :). You've done nothing wrong. Simply adjust your *Viewport clipping distance* and the triangles will go away :).